# Can the password for Wildfly credential store be changed, provided the original password is known?

Tags: wildfly, keystore, elytron

I have a credential store temp.jceks in code repository with default application passwords for developers.
When a production build is generated, the store is added in windows installer.
While installation, I need to change the store password to something else?
I know the java keystore password can be changed using keytool, so inn similar line, I was hoping the wildfly credential store password can also be changed but I do not see any option to do so with these information below.

https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/11.0/subsystem/elytron/credential-store/index.html

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/how_to_configure_server_security/securely_storing_credentials#credential_store

Any other option to secure the credential store password will be helpful.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not allow. So I had to read old values, delete the keystore used for development, create a new one with a random password and store back the values. I had to use the same name since its the one configured in standalone.xml and did want to construct standalone.xml dynamically.